# Fire Gridview RowUpdating Event without an Update/Save Button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview and I would like to Autosave the fields without using a save or an update button. How do I fire the RowUpdating Event without using a button? Or is there a better way of implementing this? Thanks for your help.

```
        <div id="form_BCFLP" class="fm_Medium5" runat="server" visible="true">
        <asp:GridView ID="GV_BCFLP" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id,Name"
            GridLines="none" Visible="true" OnRowUpdating="GV_BCFLP_RowUpdating" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostback="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ItemStyle-CssClass="lblSize_LargeBlack"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

protected void GV_BCFLP_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //I call my webservice here to update data
}
```

Comment: I've used a Drop Down List and use the selectedIndexChanged event to insert. Don't know if that would be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **RowUpdating** event requires you to do a post back which probably is not what you are looking for. For proper auto saving you dont want to (typically) disrupt the user while they are filling in the form.

Instead you may want to look at using aJAX and javascript script functions to extract the entered data from the grid view and send it to your server. This way the user does not have to wait for your auto-save to finish before continuing the form.

Now there are lots of tutorials out there on how to use aJax and other scripting tools. I would suggest going down this route.

Cheers,

Nico

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! I might use Jquery to do the same.